# Excel: formula to return a value based on another cells value

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet where one column contains cells with text of 4 characters in length. My logic is:

- If the cell contains 1111, then place F2mg in another column cell, or,
- If the cell contains 2222, then place M3TNT in that other column cell, and so on.

There are many of these instances. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Have you explored vlookup

Answer (score 2):

Use a `VLOOKUP` table. Here's a quick example:

[image]

`VLOOKUP` has the following format/interface:

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup value,
         range containing the lookup value,
         the column number in the range containing the return value,
         optionally specify TRUE for approximate match or FALSE for an exact match)
```

Consider reviewing [a detailed example and video on how to use VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).